# Design pattern for reusable, context-specific model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

In a complicated system you may have business logic related to what a user can see in a given context that you want to re-use across your system.

For example, amazon.com offers different prices to different users depending on a bunch of different rules. Those prices have to be shown consistently in search, product detail pages, email ads, etc.

If you're not yet at the place where it makes sense to extract out internal service APIs, where does this kind of user-specific model logic go in Rails-style MVC? It doesn't belong in the Model (requires too much context), but also doesn't belong in the Controller (needs to be re-used across many views in many controllers).

What are the leading design patterns for this type of problem?

Comment: In Rails, you can use view helpers for this, but they are in the global namespace and get messy. You could create `Presenter` objects or some other pattern.

Comment: Presenters seem like the obvious choice to me - this sounds like an example of complex view logic, and that's what those are for.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Presenters seem like a reasonable choice, but I've used them more for view logic ("how should this data be rendered"). My example would require the presenters querying a datastore directly, which I'm not sure is great.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe this does belong in the Model itself? Would it be bad to do something like `product.context = { user: u }`, and then have the model know to do something different when you call `model.price`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess such complex decisions should introduce a `ProductService` into your system with some `PricePipeline` inside it. When any part of the system requests a list of products, passing some filters, `ProductService` fetches products from DB, instantiates `PricePipeline` manager and passes a list of products with their initial, DB-loaded prices to each member of `PricePipeline` manager.

Some caching is obviously required, but... that's another question, isn't it? ;)